# Linking an existing repository to Visual Studio Team Services repository (Github to VSTS migration)

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

We are currently in the process of moving all of our repositories over to VSTS from Github which has been great and easy so far but are now running into the small problem of linking our old local repositories to the new ones in VSTS.

So technically they should be the exact same files except for the local ones that we weren't committing up to Github in the first place (Which we'd like to not have to manually copy back and forth). Is there a way to link these local repositories to the new ones in VSTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Just treat GitHub as a source repo here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/move-git-repos-between-team-projects)

```
git clone --mirror <repo on HitHub>
git push --mirror <remote on VSTS>
```